# How can a US President deliberately, but legally, crash the US stock markets?

Tags: discussion

Sorry!!!! please don't keep downvoting me. i just want to prepare for the worst!

Why's [How can a US President deliberately, but legally, crash the US stock markets?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/41626) off topic? I see three upvotes for

I’m voting to close this question because this is hardly in the field of economics – [Jesper Hybel](https://economics.stackexchange.com/users/10287/jesper-hybel) 12 hours ago

[Stock market crashes](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/7120) are on topic. Why wouldn't the mechanics of how a U.S. president cause one be on topic too?

Answer (score 5):

Asking broad, open-ended hypothetical questions is off-topic. Just because a question has some relation to the field of economics does not mean it is an appropriate question for this website, as we are not a forum. These sorts of questions really invite too many discussion based answers. Please see the section on [on-topic questions here](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and the section on [questions to avoid here](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Could you recommend some sites to ask questions like these?